# Windows 10 November update killed off MFP

Tags: windows-10

So I'm running the N edition of Windows 10 Pro which means I need the MFP (Media Feature Pack) to get Windows Media Player and several codecs or the `MFPlat.dll` that's often needed to play games like Black Ops 3 as an example.

I already had this before the November update, but after installing the update, it's completely removed the MFP so I have no Media Player, I can't use the edge browser to view PDFs anymore, and I can't play various games.

Of course, this prompted me to reinstall the MFP, so I went and did just that, but... Nothing has changed other than it listing that the package exists, I still can't play those games, nor do I have Media Player and PDFs still can't be opened. I tried restarting several times, I got the `Windows is updating` message on the second reboot, but that's all. If I attempt to install it again, it says it already exists, if I try to remove it, it says that I can't because it's a required package.

Is there anything else I can try to get the MFP to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft just re-released the MFP to solve this issue:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229

Comment: Trying it out now.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks man, I've got Media Player and the MFPlat.dll back.

Comment: No problem.. I was on the verge of re-installing but luckily I found this fix.

Comment: this is what I already posted yesterday with the same KB link ...

Comment: LOL @ magicandre1981... you posted the link to the old MFP the other day and just edited the new one in now. I know because I checked your solution the other day trying to solve the problem.   Also, you downvoted my answer as well? Really?

Comment: @rufus NO i posted the same link (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229). Are you unable to read? If I would edit my post there would be a version history **facepalm**

Answer (score 0):

The November update has Build 10586, so you have to [install the Media Feature Pack for this build](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229), which you can [download from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49919).

Comment: Yes, that is what I've installed. But nothing from the MFP exists on my PC other than the pack existing in `wusa`. Media Player is nowhere to be seen, Edge still wants it to display PDFs and the `MFPlat.dll` still doesn't exist. I've tried rebooting numerous times as well.

Comment: open programs & features in classic control panel and activate Media Player. Or is the Media Player still not listed there? Was the update installed correctly?